# Define custom SVN subcommand

Tags: svn

Is it possible to define a custom subcommand in SVN? I'd like to define my own `svn tkdiff` subcommand that would simply call `svn diff --diff-cmd=tkdiff` on a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Subversion can't do this as elegantly as git can, using the `[alias]` section in the `~/.gitconfig` file.

However, if you can live without the standard diff-tool, you can globally configure Subversion to use another diff tool by adding a line to `~/.subversion/config` (`%APPDATA%/Subversion/config` if you are on Windows) like so:

```
diff-cmd = tkdiff
```

If that's not an option, you can still resort to...

- adding an alias like `svntkdiff` to your `.cshrc` / `.bashrc` / ...
- writing a wrapper script that mangles a call `svn tkdiff` to do a `svn diff --diff-cmd=tkdiff` and simply passes through all other Subversion commands unmodified.